# How would you make multiple buttons in html point to the same JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want 'div#Welcome a' and 'div#Familiarize a' to point to this JS code:

```
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemClicked = $(this);
    var id = itemClicked.attr("id");
    id = id.replace(/\D/g,'');
    slider.goToSlide(id);
    return false;
```

right now i have this:

```
$('div#Welcome a').click(function(e){
```

and this:

```
$('div#Familiarize a').click(function(e){
```

for the click to go to the specified code. I was wondering if there was a way that anything that i wanted to be linked with this could could be without having to make a new function every time. Is there an ID for certain tags that i can put on?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can also use comma-separated selectors - `$('div#Welcome a, div#Familiarize a').click(function(e){...});`

Comment: Or you can add a class to both anchors and bind to that class

Comment: FYI, you can eliminate the first 4 lines of code, and just do `slider.goToSlide(this.id.replace(/\D/g,''))`. The first line isn't needed because `return false;` handles it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your code block into a named function and pass that to your event handlers:

```
function myEventHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemClicked = $(this);
    var id = itemClicked.attr("id");
    id = id.replace(/\D/g,'');
    slider.goToSlide(id);
    return false;
}

$('div#Familiarize a').click(myEventHandler);
$('div#Welcome a').click(myEventHandler);
```

Or as @mark.hch and @Huangism have pointed out, you can also use comma-separated selectors:

```
$('div#Familiarize a, div#Welcome a').click(myEventHandler);
```

Comment: `$('div#Welcome a, div#Familiarize a')` save you some characters

Comment: Isn't there a way that i can make an if or something to validate certain clicks?

Comment: Can you be more specific @Kingrune?

Comment: Kind of like what @Barmar is saying where you would add a class to a div except could this be done directly to the a tag? an example being "an a tag is click check to see whether it has _____ class and if it does run the function

Comment: You could use `if(itemClicked.hasClass('whateverclass')) { // do stuff }`

Comment: if the itemClicked does not have the specified class how would you get it to act normally?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but I recommend you find what is common between them, code mainly for that and then you can `if(itemClick.hasClass('whateverClass')) { // do special stuff for has class } else { // doesn't have class, do other stuff }`

Comment: Sorry, i'm not explaining very well, there could be 2 scenarios: one is where the the link needs to be a slide pointer so the block of code that is posted. The other scenario being that the link has to be a regular link pointing to a website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple selectors together by separating them with comma.

```
$('div#Familiarize a, div#Welcome a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemClicked = $(this);
    var id = itemClicked.attr("id");
    id = id.replace(/\D/g,'');
    slider.goToSlide(id);
    return false;
});
```

Although to simplify things, I suggest giving all the relevant `DIV`s a common class, and using that in the selector: `$('div.tab a').click(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also give each div the same class and attach the handler to that.

```
<div class="thisclass">

$('.thisclass').click(function (e) {

}
```